# Заголовок по ширине картинки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть горизонтальный список, состоящий из картинок и заголовков под ними. Хочу сделать, чтобы заголовок зависел от ширины картинки.

Получил ширину всех картинок. Сейчас всем заголовкам приходит одна и та же ширина.

JS:

```
$(".project-img img").one('load', function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    $('.projects h1').css('width', width);
    console.log(width);
})
.each(function() {
    if (this.complete)
        $(this).trigger('load');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="projects">
    <div>
        <a href="#someproject1" title="someproject1">
            <span class="project-img">
                <img src="./img/project1.jpg" alt="someproject1" title="someproject1" />
            </span>
            <h1>Название проекта1</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#someproject2" title="someproject2">
            <span class="project-img">
                <img src="./img/project2.jpg" alt="someproject2" title="someproject2" />
            </span>
            <h1>Название проекта2</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#someproject3" title="someproject3">
            <span class="project-img">
                <img src="./img/project3.jpg" alt="someproject3" title="someproject3" />
            </span>
            <h1>Название проекта3</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну логично, всем `h1` внутри списка.

Comment: HTML добавил, изменил. Логичным то, что пока добавляется `width`, а то, что последняя и есть суть проблемы.

Comment: Можно было бы без скриптов обойтись...

Comment: @Qwertiy, никто не мешает Вам поделиться своим безскриптовым вариантом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Добавил `div`'ам внутри `.projects` класс `project`, а `h1` - класс `project-header`. При желании можно обойтись без этого, но с классами решение более гибкое.
- Ширина теперь устанавливает только для заголовка внутри блока с картинкой, а не для всех заголовков.
- Так как в заголовках используется крупный шрифт, то в примере они не выглядят как элементы нужной ширины. Однако можно убедиться, что в их стилях установлены соответствующие значения `width`.
- Помогает ли `if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');` на практике - не знаю, но из кода убирать не стал.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".project-img img").one('load', function() {
        var width = $(this).width();
        var header = $(this).closest('.project').find('.project-header');
        header.css('width', width);
    })
    .each(function() {
        if (this.complete)
            $(this).trigger('load');
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="projects">
    <div class="project">
        <a href="#someproject1" title="someproject1">
            <span class="project-img">
                <img src="http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png" alt="someproject1" title="someproject1" />
            </span>
            <h1 class="project-header">Название проекта1</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <a href="#someproject2" title="someproject2">
            <span class="project-img">
                <img src="http://waytoeast.ru/images/page_bg.jpg" alt="someproject2" title="someproject2" />
            </span>
            <h1 class="project-header">Название проекта2</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <a href="#someproject3" title="someproject3">
            <span class="project-img">
                <img src="http://waytoeast.ru/images/border.png" alt="someproject3" title="someproject3" />
            </span>
            <h1 class="project-header">Название проекта3</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Получение заголовка без добавления классов:

```
var header = $(this).closest('a').find('h1');
```

Comment: Благодарю! Единственное по поводу ` $('.projects h1')` я не совсем понял, почему стили будут присваиваться все заголовкам? Ведь `$(".project-img img)` выбирает картинки из области `.project-img`, или я что-то не так понял.

Comment: @Promark на здоровье. Потому что селектор `".projects h1"` подразумевает выбор **всех** `h1` внутри **всех** `.projects`. `.css()` устанавливает стили для всех выбранных селектором элементов. С `".project-img img"` ситуация аналогичная.

Comment: Ну значит я все правильно понял, просто там других `h1` не подразумевалось. Еще раз спасибо!)